# Random path in svg in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I wrote the following javaScript to try to draw a random path in an svg.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    function randomPath(){
    var x = Math.trunc(Math.random());
    var y = Math.trunc(Math.random());
    var xstep = 0;
    var ystep = 0;
    var path = '0,0';
    for (i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
          path += ' ';
          path += (x).toString();
          path += ',';
          path += (y).toString();
          xstep = Math.random();
          ystep = Math.random();
          xstep *= 10;
          ystep *= 10;
          x += Math.trunc(xstep);
          y += Math.trunc(ystep);
        };
        return path;
      };

    var figure = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    figure.id = 'brownian-figure';
    figure.setAttribute('height', '400pt');
    figure.setAttribute('width', '200pt');

    var pathArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    pathArray[i] = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polyline');
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var path = randomPath();
    alert(path);
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('points', path);
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('style', 'fill:none;stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1);stroke-width:1');
    figure.appendChild(pathArray[i]);
    };

    var divfigure = document.createElement('div');
    divfigure.id = 'divfigure';
    divfigure.style = 'margin:0pt;padding:0pt;border:0pt none;background-color:rgba(240,240,240,1);position:absolute;top:100pt;left:100pt;width:200pt;height:400pt;';
    divfigure.appendChild(figure);

    document.body.appendChild(divfigure);
  };
</script>
```

Notice there are only 2 steps in the for in the `randomPath()` function.

The code **does run** and draws with that small value for the number of steps. There is an `alert(path)` over there to let me see the path before I try to assign it.

However, **with 3 steps or more in the `for` inside `randomPath()` the code breaks**. The `alert(path)` still shows the longer path, but the script gives the error

```
TypeError: pathArray[i] is undefined
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('points', path);
```

If I replace `path` in the line with the error, by an explicit path (output by `randomPath()`), say `'0,0 0,0 4,8 8,15'` it still doesn't work. But if I do it and also remove the call to the `randomPath()` function it works again.

I am confused. It seems to be that the function `randomPath()` works well since the `alert` displays a well-formed string. The svg also works with the same string input explicitly. But the two together don't work for some reason.

What is the problem?

Comment: why at closing of forloop you have have semicolon

Comment: @CY5 I don't know. I am beginning to learn javaScript on my own. I grew up writing it and the `for` seems to run. Should I remove it?

Comment: i don't get that error http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVOyNB  I have removed unwanted semicolon from your code

Comment: @CY5 Yes, there is no error with 2 steps in the for loop. Now change it to 3 steps or more.

Comment: You have not `var`d `i` in `randomPath` or in your load handler, so both are using the same `i` in the global namespace, meaning you have an identifier conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is becoz inside last for loop you have initialise `i` and incremented it and then you call randomPath() which also contain `i` and that function increment it to 3 times so when it comes out function you have `i` value 3 
so you get error on `pathArray[i].setAttribute('points', path);`   changed it to k or something in randomPath() and also intialize variable as `var identifier` if don't want it to be global

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var path = randomPath();

    }
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

    function randomPath(){
    var x = Math.trunc(Math.random());
    var y = Math.trunc(Math.random());
    var xstep = 0;
    var ystep = 0;
    var path = '0,0';
    for (k = 0; k < 3 ; k++) {
          path += ' ';
          path += (x).toString();
          path += ',';
          path += (y).toString();
          xstep = Math.random();
          ystep = Math.random();
          xstep *= 10;
          ystep *= 10;
          x += Math.trunc(xstep);
          y += Math.trunc(ystep);
        }
        return path;
      }

    var figure = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    figure.id = 'brownian-figure';
    figure.setAttribute('height', '400pt');
    figure.setAttribute('width', '200pt');

    var pathArray = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    pathArray[j] = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polyline');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var path = randomPath();
    alert(path);
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('points', path);
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('style', 'fill:none;stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1);stroke-width:1');
    figure.appendChild(pathArray[i]);
    }

    var divfigure = document.createElement('div');
    divfigure.id = 'divfigure';
    divfigure.style = 'margin:0pt;padding:0pt;border:0pt none;background-color:rgba(240,240,240,1);position:absolute;top:100pt;left:100pt;width:200pt;height:400pt;';
    divfigure.appendChild(figure);

    document.body.appendChild(divfigure);
  };
```

Comment: I see. Is it because javaScript functions are like inline functions, the code of the function gets copied in each call?

Comment: even your `i` is global becoz you have not used var keyword to initialise it

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to catch that. In the [examples on for loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) they didn't use `var` to declare the `for` variable. Thank you.

Comment: @myfirsttime1 Go with  Mozilla MDN it is accurate for Learning Web Technology https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: I just tried it with `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` and it does work. So, if I understand correctly, when using the declaration `var i` inside the `for` the variable is local to the for, and without the declaration it is global. That's unusual, isn't it?